# Visualization.query is not recognising the date from a function Google Appscript

Tags: google-apps-script, google-visualization, google-apps

Currently using Visualization API with Google App Script calling the

'index.html' via the doGet() function.

I'm using the visualization to produce a custom table using the visualization.Query() function and inserting the actual query using the URIComponent.

### All works great when the query is hardcoded in.

The date function which brings back the date i want to query.

```
function subtractDaysFromDate(date,d){
// d = number of day ro substract and date = start date
var result = new Date(date.getTime()-d*(24*3600*1000));
var x = String(Utilities.formatDate(result, "GMT", "yyyy-MM-dd"));
return x
}

 function subtractedDateForUrl() {
 var test = String(subtractDaysFromDate(new Date(),5));
 Logger.log(test)     
 }
```

The subtractedDateForUrl() returns the exact string i want in the Logger.log(test);

[17-05-22 02:26:43:562 PDT] 2017-05-17

I've then called the subtractDateForUrl() to bring the date so i can add this in the query.

```
 var dateString1 = subtractDateForUrl();
 //Works
 var query = encodeURIComponent("SELECT * WHERE A = date '2017-05-17'");
 //Does not work
 var query = encodeURIComponent("SELECT * WHERE A = date '" + dateString1 + "'");
```

This is exactly the same but for some reason it does not work.

I've tried the following (which does not work for either);

```
 var removeQuotes = dateString1.replace(/\"+/g,"")
 var query = encodeURIComponent("SELECT * WHERE A = date '" + removeQuotes + 
 "'");
  var convertToHtmlOutput = 
 HtmlService.createHtmlOutput(dateString1).getContent()
 var query = encodeURIComponent("SELECT * WHERE A = date '" + convertToHtmlOutput + "'");
```

Answer (score 0):

the following function doesn't return anything...

```
function subtractedDateForUrl() {
  var test = String(subtractDaysFromDate(new Date(),5));
  Logger.log(test);
}
```

as such, here, `dateString1` will be `undefined`

```
var dateString1 = subtractDateForUrl();
```

---

try adding a `return` statement...

```
function subtractedDateForUrl() {
  var test = String(subtractDaysFromDate(new Date(),5));
  Logger.log(test);
  return test;
}
```

Comment: I've added the return and tested the Logger to make sure it returns correctly. Still doesn't work. It's seem the entire code won't work if the function is in the variable (I.e var dataString1 = subtractDateForUrl()). It seems to work using a different structured function but i cannot subtract days from that particular function (getNowDate()).   [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31419110/query-setquery-to-current-day-with-google-apps-script)